# Dynamically adjust the height of an elements so they always stick to a single page

Tags: css, sass, responsive-design

I have a couple of elements on my page

[image]

I want to be able to change the height of `A` and `B` dynamically based on screen height so the `A` and `B` elements so they always stick to the single screen without a need to scroll down.

Currently I am using the media queries to adjust the height of my elements

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) and (max-width: 5000px) {
  .A{
    height: 600x;
  }
  .B{
    margin-right: 400px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1279px) and (max-width: 1919px) {
  .A{
    height: 550px;
  }
  .B{
    height: 350px;
}
```

But that solution is a bit silly as I would prefer the height of `A` and `B` dynamically changes based on current height without a need to write too much media queries for each screen size as that might be quite a lot.

Is there any smart solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

We can use Flexbox to solve this with a columnar direction.

- Since you used `600px`/`400px` in your original code, I used `6` and `4` as `flex-grow` values for `.a.` and `.b.`, respectively.
- These `flex-grow` values are relative, so `.6`, `.4` or `600` `400` would yield the same result.
- `header` and `footer` take up whatever room remains in the container after `.a` and `b` take their space.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container > * {
  padding: .5em;
}

.a {
  flex-grow: 6;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.b {
  flex-grow: 4;
  background-color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>header</header>
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j3kxr50L/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
  <!-- language: lang-css -->
    try this one

    * {
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       box-sizing:border-box;
     }

     .container {
          height: 100vh; // this can gives (.container) height according to view screen
      }

     .a{
         height: calc(60vh - 40px);//minus the header height
       }

      .b{
         height: calc(40vh - 60px); //minus the footer height
        }



<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <div class="container">
      <header>header</header>
      <div class="a">A</div>
      <div class="b">B</div>
      <footer>footer</footer>
    </div>
```